# How to get the guid for the site collection or site or for a list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We can use the following for taking any site collection object.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySiteCollection/mySite");
```

But, in the future I can change my site url to `"http://mySiteCollection/YourSite"`. I think the solution for this problem is uisng the GUID. How can I view the guid of a particular sitecollection or site? I have the same issue with the List.

I believe that I can retrieve the Guid using the below powershell commands.

```
PS > $mysite =  Get-SPSite <SITE_URL>
PS > $mysite.id
```

But I don't know if there is any way to view the guid using powershell?

Comment: $site = Get-SPSite "http://myserver:10115" 
$web = $site.OpenWeb(myweb) 
write-host $site.id         // this work
write-host $web.id          // this not work .... hmmm

Comment: I want other than power shell

Answer (score 3):

you have to retrieve the site via something.

If you don't want to use the URL you can use the Guid as you suggested or you could use the title of the root web.

Use this to see some more options

`get-spsite | select Url,ID, RootWeb`

Changing the SPSite URL is straight forward, I would just use the URL.

Comment: What is difeerence between SPSIte URL and just URL? I am first time listening to this words.. :)

Comment: I meant to say changing the SPSite URL isn't straight forward. So I would just use the URL to find the site.

Comment: or Get-SPWebApplication |  select name,id

Answer (score 2):

Actually without using code there is one way, if you have Google Chrome or Firefox -> Firebug you can get the id by going to "Content and Structure" right click on "-"  "+" icon of which you want to know the id.  you will see something like this `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('TreeView1','sArea:?SPWeb:31f18323-e7da-4b9a-8a09-293f24449589:\\SPList:35a33810-52c9-456d-adbb-8d1a819176f0?SPWeb:31f18323-e7da-4b9a-8a09-293f24449589:')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(TreeView1_Data, this,'TreeView1t39');" id="TreeView1t39i" tabindex="-1"><img src="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" alt="List" style="border-width:0;"></a>`  SpWeb: is your SpWeb id and SPList is your list id. You can also verify list id by going to list settings.